# WebApplicationInitializer onStartup() not getting triggered

Tags: java, spring, websphere-8, servlet-3.0

I have a spring project running on WebSphere App Server v8.5 and I'm trying to get rid of my web.xml using WebApplicationInitializer but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the initializer:

```
public class InflowInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("In initializer");
    }

}
```

I have spring-web, spring-mvc and javax.servlet-api all included in my pom.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.fmr.bpo.asyncprocessingframework</groupId>
<artifactId>apf-inflow-web</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-M3</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fmr.bpo.asyncprocessingframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>apf-base</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fmr.bpo.asyncprocessingframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>apf-base-xen-parser</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>    
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

It's a dynamic web module 3.0 project and I'm compiling with Java 6.

Is there anything apart from implementing WebApplicationInitializer that I need to do to get this working? The container is supposed to scan and pickup any class that implements the interface right? I want to load all my spring configs through the onStartup but control never reaches there when I deploy the app to the server.

The documentation says that I need to have a servlet 3.0 container. I don't really know how to verify if I'm running on one. WebSphere 8.5 is relatively recent so it would be running 3.0 I guess.

Appreciate the help, thanks.

**EDIT**

Adding dependency tree:

```
[INFO] com.fmr.bpo.asyncprocessingframework:apf-inflow-web:war:1.0.0-M3
[INFO] +- com.fmr.bpo.asyncprocessingframework:apf-base:jar:1.0.0-M3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fmr.bpo.asyncprocessingframework:apf-base-xen-parser:jar:1.0.0-M3:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-http:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl:jar:1.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- io.fastjson:boon:jar:0.33:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.4:compile
[INFO] +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mail:jar:4.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.2.2.RELEASE:compile
```

Comment: Set the `javax.servlet` dependency to provided.

Comment: Tried with and without the dependency and after setting it to provided. Still not detecting it.

Comment: Add the output of `mvn dependency:tree`.